# Different Time Stamps in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Please help me know difference in following SQL statements in Amazon Redshift: -

```
extract(epoch from
          trunc(convert_timezone('Asia/Calcutta', getDate())
                - 27)
       )::bigint * 1000000
```

vs

```
trunc(convert_timezone('Asia/Calcutta',getDate())
      -27)
- INTERVAL '05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE
```

Please help me with relevant online documents which explain in detail.

Comment: The answer depends on the definition of the function `convert_timezone`, which we don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: [GETDATE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GETDATE.html) will return TIMESTAMP in UTC, irrespective of where Server is located.

Step 2: [convert_timezone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/CONVERT_TIMEZONE.html) converted UTC timestamp into IST.

Step 3: -27 took converted timestamp to 27 days ago.

Step 4: [trunc()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNC.html) removed time from timestamp, thus making it date without time in IST.

Step 5: [extract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html) converted IST date into epoch seconds.

Step 6: [Interval](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_interval_literals.html) uses datepart and quantity, where abbreviations and plurals of datepart are optional